# How to initialize EasyLoading "You should call EasyLoading.init() in your MaterialApp"

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main(){
  runApp(  MaterialApp(
    home: const login(),
    builder: EasyLoading.init(),
  ));
  configLoading();
}
```

By Using the MU code, even though I initialized `EasyLoading` I kept getting the following error, is there any other initialization required?

```
*E/flutter ( 9370): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter_easyloading/src/easy_loading.dart': Failed assertion: line 425 pos 7: 'overlayEntry != null': You should call EasyLoading.init() in your MaterialApp
E/flutter ( 9370): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 9370): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #2      EasyLoading._show (package:flutter_easyloading/src/easy_loading.dart:425:7)
E/flutter ( 9370): #3      EasyLoading.showSuccess (package:flutter_easyloading/src/easy_loading.dart:317:22)
E/flutter ( 9370): #4      _loginState.initState (package:lampreg/login.dart:58:17)
E/flutter ( 9370): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5015:57)
E/flutter ( 9370): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 9370): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 9370): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 9370): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #25     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter ( 9370): #26     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #27     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #28     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
E/flutter ( 9370): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter ( 9370): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6300:14)
E/flutter ( 9370): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter ( 9370): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter ( 9370): #36     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter ( 9370): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)*
```